# Get routes that use certain middleware or are in certain group?

Tags: laravel

Is it possible in Laravel in Controller, to get all routes that are in one group, or routes that use certain middleware or something else?
Here is an example of what I mean:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'admin])->group(function () {
    Route::patch('/updateClient', 'ClientController@update');
    Route::resource('server-groups','ServerGroupsController');
});
```

And in my controller to have something like this, that will get me all routes where middleware is `admin`:

```
$routes = Route::where('middleware', 'admin');
```

Currently I can only get all routes with this code:

```
$routes = Route::getRoutes();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found built-in method `middleware()` that I can use on route and it will give me an array of middlewares, same as @tcj mentioned in his answer. So I took all routes and through loop I added all routes that have desired middleware to a new collection.

```
 $routes = Route::getRoutes();
 $new_routes = new Collection;
 foreach ($routes as $route) {
     $middleware = $route->middleware();
     for ($i = 0; $i < count($middleware); $i++) {
         if ($middleware[$i] == 'admin') {
             $new_routes ->push($route);
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use laravel's built-in [gatherMiddleware()](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_gatherMiddleware) method that will return all middlewares attached to a route in an array, by default it will include the `web` route but you can remove it if you want, also, use the route method from the request helper.

```
$routes = request()->route()->gatherMiddleware();

dd($routes); // will display : array(0 => 'web', 1 => 'auth', 2 => 'admin');

dd(array_slice($routes, 1, null, true)) // will display : array(1 => 'auth', 2 => 'admin');
```